# Issue in parsing SOAP/XML using java

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I had writing a java program to parser a SOAP/XML. This is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.id = 123;
    customer.firstName = "Jane";
    customer.lastName = "Doe";
    QName root = new QName("return");
    JAXBElement<Customer> je = new JAXBElement<Customer>(root, Customer.class, customer);

    XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamWriter xsw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
    xsw.writeStartDocument();
    xsw.writeStartElement("soapenv", "Envelope", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    xsw.writeStartElement("soapenv", "Body", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    xsw.writeStartElement("", "InitializePayment", "http://service.jaxws.blog/");
    xsw.writeStartElement("", "request", "http://service.jaxws.blog/");

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(je, xsw);

    xsw.writeEndDocument();
    xsw.close();
}
```

I am getting output like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <InitializePayment>
     <request>
      <return id="123">
       <firstName>Jane</firstName>
       <lastName>Doe</lastName>
      </return>
     </request>
    </InitializePayment>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But i need the output i which the `id` must be present as a tag inside a `<return>`. like this

```
<return>
 <id>123</id>
  <firstName>Jane</firstName>
  <lastName>Doe</lastName>
</return>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove the `@XmlAttribute` annotation on the `id` field/property.

---

> thanks it works. But url which in a envelope is not come in output

You need to leverage the `writeNamespace` and `writeDefaultNamespace` methods as follows:

```
    xsw.writeStartElement("soapenv", "Envelope", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    xsw.writeNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    xsw.writeStartElement("soapenv", "Body", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    xsw.writeStartElement("", "InitializePayment", "http://service.jaxws.blog/");
    xsw.writeDefaultNamespace("http://service.jaxws.blog/");
    xsw.writeStartElement("", "request", "http://service.jaxws.blog/");
```

Comment: thanks it works. But url which in a `envelope` is not come in output

Comment: @SatheeshSanthosh - It should get written out.  Here is a link to an example that I put together that you can compare against:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Comment: i just copied your code completely but i won't come

Comment: @SatheeshSanthosh - Try adding the `writeNamespace` method:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html#writeNamespace(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: could you tell me how to insert the `writeNamespace` inside the program

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69736/discussion-between-satheesh-santhosh-and-blaise-doughan).

Comment: @SatheeshSanthosh - I have updated my answer to solve your namespace issue.